# Error inserting data into two joined serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am making an application in Django Rest Framework which the user can register multiple tasks in a project, but I am running into a problem and it is that when I want to record the data it generates an error where it says that task_id cannot be null:
This my model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=timezone.now())
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=timezone.now())

class Project(models.Model):
    developer = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_project = models.DateTimeField()
    end_project = models.DateTimeField()
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_state = models.ForeignKey(ProjectState, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=timezone.now)
```

This my serializer:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = (
            'title', 'description'
        )
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    start_project = serializers.DateField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'])
    end_project = serializers.DateField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'])
    task = TaskSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = (
            'developer', 'title', 'description', 'start_project', 'end_project', 'task', 'project_state'
        )
```

This is the json that I send:

```
{
    "developer": [
        1
    ],
    "title": "Inicio",
    "description": "Iniciar",
    "start_project": "1999-02-02",
    "end_project": "1999-02-02",
    "task": [
        {
            "title": "Titulo",
            "description": "empezar"
        }
    ],
    "project_state": 1
}
```

When I show the response by console it returns the complete data:

```
data={'developer': [1], 'title': 'Inicio', 'description': 'Iniciar', 'start_project': '1999-02-02', 'end_project': '1999-02-02', 'task': [{'title': 'Titulo', 'description': 'empezar'}], 'project_state': 1}
```

But when I want to get the data from the serializer it doesn't show me the tasks:

```
{'developer': [1], 'title': 'Inicio', 'description': 'Iniciar', 'start_project': '1999-02-02', 'end_project': '1999-02-02', 'project_state': 1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put `read_only=True` for your `task` field.

In the [DRF serializer fields docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/) they say about `read_only` that:

> Read-only fields are included in the API output, but should not be included in the input during create or update operations. Any 'read_only' fields that are incorrectly included in the serializer input will be ignored.

> Set this to True to ensure that the field is used when serializing a representation, but is not used when creating or updating an instance during deserialization.

And if you don't put `read_only` for that field, you will have to write an explicit `.create()` method for your serializer if you want to be able to use create operations.

If you want to create `Task` objects for each task in your sent json, and associate them with the `Project` object that will be created, the method can look like this:

```py
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # [...]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tasks_data = validated_data.pop("task")
        project = Project.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for task_data in tasks_data:
            task = Task.objects.create(**task_data)
            project.task.add(task)
        return project
```

### Specific code with the model information

I have renamed the `task` `ForeignKey` to `project` and moved it in `Task` model, because from your serialisers' structure I guess that you want one project to have several tasks and not the contrary. The name `task` still exists as a related name.

I have also added your slug fields in the serializers as they are mandatory and have to be unique in your models.

The models:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=timezone.now())
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=timezone.now())
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        "Project", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="task"
    )


class Project(models.Model):
    developer = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_project = models.DateTimeField()
    end_project = models.DateTimeField()
    project_state = models.ForeignKey(ProjectState, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=timezone.now)
```

The serializers:

```py
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ("title", "description", "slug")


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    start_project = serializers.DateTimeField(input_formats=["%Y-%m-%d"])
    end_project = serializers.DateTimeField(input_formats=["%Y-%m-%d"])
    task = TaskSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = (
            "developer",
            "title",
            "description",
            "slug",
            "start_project",
            "end_project",
            "task",
            "project_state",
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tasks_data = validated_data.pop("task")
        developers_data = validated_data.pop("developer")
        project = Project.objects.create(**validated_data)
        project.developer.set(developers_data)
        for task_data in tasks_data:
            task = Task.objects.create(**task_data, project=project)
            project.task.add(task)
        return project
```

Example of POST request:

```json
{
    "developer": [
        1
    ],
    "title": "Inicio",
    "description": "Iniciar",
    "slug": "inicio",
    "start_project": "1999-02-02",
    "end_project": "1999-02-02",
    "task": [
        {
            "title": "Titulo",
            "description": "empezar",
            "slug": "titulo"
        }
    ],
    "project_state": 1
}
```

Comment: it generates the following error Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use developer.set() instead.

Comment: Could you add your models ?